# Is an identity functor in Category of sets a function application?

Tags: functions, category-theory

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/identity+functor

> The identity functor on a category C is the functor idC:C→C that maps
> each object and morphism of C to itself. The identity functors are the
> identities for composition of functors in Cat.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+application

> A function f is defined by its association to each input value x
> (belonging to some allowable domain of values) of an output value,
> usually denoted f(x) or fx. The process of passing from f and x to
> f(x) is called function application, and one speaks of applying f to x
> to produce f(x).

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Set

Is an identity functor in Category of sets a function application?

The reason I ask this is in programming such as F#, pipeline operator

https://riptutorial.com/fsharp/example/14158/pipe-forward-and-backward

```
 "Hello World" |> print

 value |> f
```

Now,

```
 value |> map(f)
```

is generally recognized as functor.

In this understanding, a simple function application

```
 value |> f
```

should be an identity functor, is this correct?

Thanks.

### EDIT

**(endo)Functor**

```
value |> map(f)
```

**identityFunctor** (special case: `map` == `identity`)

```
value |> identity(f)
```

Therefore, **identityFunctor** is equivalent to

**function application**

```
value |> f
```

in another notation,

```
f(value)
```

Comment: Would a restatement of your question be: Does $A\rightarrow B$ imply $A\rightarrow id_\mathbf{Set}(B)$? In other words, is $id_\mathbf{Set}$ *returning* the object, rather than *encapsulating* it? For comparison, the `Identity` functor in Haskell is an encapsulation, and one must "extract" the value to use it.

Comment: I always think it's not a good idea to switch concept between programming and mathematics. Especially in category theory, I' ve seen many people says "XX in programming and XX in math is different".  So if you observe the implementation of  `identity` functor in Haskell is somewhat specific than category theory, the Haskell guys must be wrong.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry Having said that, the talk on C->D or A→idSet(B) seems wrong because it's not C->C that is the identity.

Comment: To clarify, I was asking if OP is making a distinction between "$id_\mathbf{Set}(A)$ *can be directly used as* $A$" vs. "$id_\mathbf{Set}(A)$ is *isomorphic to* $A$". The rest of the content of my comment was just to illustrate a situation where the former doesn't hold. To me this is a question worth asking if it's actually OP's intention. If not, I have yet to understand the question.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry Yes, pipeline operator `x |> f` is another expression of `f(x)` (there are some spec difference https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator ), so can be directly used as A"

Comment: and I think "identity functor" that encapsulate (wrap) a naked value with another object/type is not identity functor of category theory. I forgot the term, but there must be different naming.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry I clarified this point in my EDIT. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

It's basically fine* to think of the object part of a functor $C\to D$ as a function between the set of objects of $C$ and the set of objects of $D$. However, it's important to note that that's not all the information of the functor: it also involves a function from the set of morphisms of $C$ to the set of morphisms of $D$, together with some requirements on the morphism function and how the two functions relate.

*The concern is that $C$ and $D$ might have a proper class, not a set, of objects, but this makes no practical difference in this situation, and is certainly not of interest to a type-theoretic system like Haskell. It is perhaps worth noting that the object part of the identity functor of the category of sets is *not* a morphism in the category of sets, since the class of all sets is not itself a set.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbf{Set}$ is *large* (i.e., it has more objects than can be accounted for with a set), and since function application takes *all* values from one set to values in another set, a functor from $\mathbf{Set}$ can't technically be a function.

Comment: Couldn't we drop that assumption from the definition of function? nLab speaks of _allowable_ domain, but I don't know if that includes proper classes or not.

Comment: @Dog_69 Yeah, this isn't a very important concern. One can certainly define functions between proper classes, although usually sets are assumed.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't the functor be a *class* of functions? In particular, since some objects in a proper class have yet to be conceived, the functor remains undefined for objects we don't yet know about. So, it's more of a *rule* for creating a new function when the situation arises. If dropping the distinction between set and class is allowable, I'm not sure what the original question is asking.

Comment: More specifically, if $id_\mathbf{Set}$ was a function on sets, then you'd have $id_\mathbf{Set}\in\mathbf{Set}$. So, it's clearly of a different type than canonical functions.

Comment: @Kevin P. Berry yes, I misunderstood the question. Certainty you can drop such an assumption, so you can still talk of a function, but certainty it will not be an element in $\mathbf{Set}$ precisely because od what you said (which is also mentioned in Kevins Arlin's answer).

Comment: @Dog_69 I clarified this point in my EDIT. Thank you again.